# Showing Percentage on every row

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I would like to show the percentage of gender on every row of the sql result. My data looks like:

```
 CREATE TABLE Results
 ( employeeId varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
 , Employee_Name varchar(228) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
 , gender varchar(1) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
 , Citizenship varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

 insert into Results values
 (1,'A','M','India'),
 (2,'B','F','India'),
 (4,'D','F','France'),
 (3,'C','F','Lebanon'),
 (5,'E','M','Sri Lanka');
```

The percentage by gender count would be *M 40, F 60* by using

```
select gender, round(count(gender) * 100/sum(count(gender)) over (),2)  percentage 
  from Results 
 group 
    by gender;
```

This query will return the result for M & F but i would like the percentage to be repeated for every row in the table,

```
employeeId  EmployeeName    gender Citizenship    Percentage
        1           A          M        India          40 
        2           B          F        India          60
        4           D          F        France         60
        3           C          F        Lebanon        60
        5           E          M       Sri Lanka       40
```

How can i do this ?

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dba89d7c62730269e603f63ef505ec3a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for `group by` or any joins.
Use `COUNT()` window function only:

```
select *, 
  round(100.0 * count(*) over (partition by gender) / count(*) over (), 2) percentage 
from Results 
order by employeeId
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=861b2dc5684185c025233253b128f66b).
Results:

```
> employeeId | Employee_Name | gender | Citizenship | percentage
> :--------- | :------------ | :----- | :---------- | ---------:
> 1          | A             | M      | India       |      40.00
> 2          | B             | F      | India       |      60.00
> 3          | C             | F      | Lebanon     |      60.00
> 4          | D             | F      | France      |      60.00
> 5          | E             | M      | Sri Lanka   |      40.00
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just join to a subquery which finds the percentage for each gender:

```
SELECT
    t1.employeeId,
    t1.EmployeeName,
    t1.gender,
    t1.Citizenship,
    t2.pct AS Percentage
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT gender, ROUND(100.0 * COUNT(*) / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (), 2) AS pct
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY gender
) t2
    ON t1.gender = t2.gender;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo